# freeRADIUS TACACS error Invalid type "Authentication-Start" in listen section

Tags: freeradius

I'm trying to use freeRADIUS with a TACACS virtual server.  In my `tacacs` file (which is bascially just a copy of https://freeradius.org/documentation/freeradius-server/4.0.0/raddb/sites-available/tacacs.html) there is this defined:

```
    listen {
        type = Authentication-Start
        type = Authentication-Continue
        type = Authorization-Request
        type = Accounting-Request
        transport = tcp
        tcp {
            port = 49
            ipaddr = *
        }
```

when i try to start the freeRADIUS service i get an error in syslog saying: `freeradius[4140523]: /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/tacacs[21]: Invalid type "Authentication-Start" in listen section.`

Seems like it doesn't like any of those tacacs message types.  Any ideas?